# Is there an "article class clone" for ConTeXt available anywhere?

Tags: context, article

I'm trying to get to grips with ConTeXt. It is an interesting system. Coming from LaTeX though, it is quite a significant change. Is there some sort of a ConTeXt template for e.g. a LaTeX article class clone that I can study to understand how this typesetting system works? Something that would be familiar to me coming from LaTeX so that I can identify what macro is effecting what on the output.

Comment: Look at the style files for [PracTeX Journal](https://gitorious.org/context/context/source/088de88944c1f2254250bb448c7371a87ff7ee39:tex/context/base/s-ptj-01.tex) and [MAPS](https://gitorious.org/context/context/source/088de88944c1f2254250bb448c7371a87ff7ee39:tex/context/base/s-map-10.mkiv)

Comment: @Aditya I posted a rather less involved solution: perhaps you might critic it! (I've gone just for the essentials of `article` in one-column mode.)

Answer (score 6):

As the LaTeX `article` class is pretty basic, quite a bit of what it does can be reproduced in ConTeXt with little effort. For example, a quick look at the ConTeXt wiki gives details for [abstracts](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Article_Abstracts), [titles](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Document_Titles) and [font selection](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Basic_Text_Formatting), while a little more effort in the [manual](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_reference_manual) also points the way for headers and footers. That might lead to something like

```
\definestartstop
  [abstract]
  [before={%
            \midaligned{\bf Abstract}%
            \blank[medium]%
            \startnarrower[2*middle]
            \tfx
         },
    after={%
            \stopnarrower
            \blank[big]%
          }%
  ]

\define\maketitle{%
  \startalignment[center]
    \blank[force,2*big]
      {%
        \tfd
        \getvariable{metadata}{title}% 
        \par
      }%
    \blank[3*medium]
    {%
      \tfa
      \getvariable{metadata}{author}%
      \par
    }%
    \blank[2*medium]
    {%
      \tfa
      \getvariable{metadata}{date}%
      \par
    }%
    \blank[3*medium]
  \stopalignment
}

\setvariables
  [metadata]
  [
     title=Some things I did,
    author=Joseph Wright,
      date=Today,
  ]

\setupheadertexts
\setupfootertexts[pagenumber]

\starttext

\maketitle

\startabstract
  This is some abstract text: it is not very interesting.
  This is some abstract text: it is not very interesting.
  This is some abstract text: it is not very interesting.
  This is some abstract text: it is not very interesting.
  This is some abstract text: it is not very interesting.
\stopabstract

\section{Introduction}

This is just some filler text to make this document work.
This is just some filler text to make this document work.
This is just some filler text to make this document work.
This is just some filler text to make this document work.
This is just some filler text to make this document work.
This is just some filler text to make this document work.
This is just some filler text to make this document work.

\stoptext
```

which is of course not 100% identical to a standard LaTeX article but is in the same direction.

Comment: Nitpicking comment: Use `{\tfa ... \endgraf}` etc to make sure that line height is correct for multi-line titles.

Comment: ConTeXt uses `\unexpanded` to create protected commands and not `\protected` but you can get rid of this when you use `\define\maketitle{...}`.

Comment: @Aditya Yes, should have spotted the wiki version is in need of a slight improvement. Am I 'OK' In ConTeXt terms using `\par` here or is `\endgraf` always used?

Comment: @Metafox Should have remembered that: I've gone with `\define` as my understanding is that's the preferred approach for 'document' macros (as opposed to ones inside an `\unprotect` block).

Comment: @JosephWright You can use `\par` without problems because ConTeXt MkIV uses `\long` for all definitions.

Comment: @Metafox I'm sure it does (much the same plan in LaTeX development code): I meant more 'is this the usual formulation' as Aditya said `\endgraf`.

Comment: @JosephWright There is no convention for this but I would only use `\par` because this is enough for a normal ConTeXt user. People who write their own code can still use `\endgraf` or `\normalpar` but things should be kept simple for normal users.

Comment: @JosephWright: I use `\endgraf` out of habit. I quick grep of the context sources show that `\endgraf` is used 137 times while `\par` is used 286 times. Of course, grepping is not a reliable metric.